# QT compiled program (which runs within QT IDE) wont run using the terminal

Tags: c++, qt, terminal, sensors, qthread

so i've made a little program to get sensor data and plot it in a graph.
While the program compiles and runs fine within QT (Debug or Release), it wont start within the terminal. Furthermore once I'm activating the "use terminal" setting within the QT project settings I'm getting the same issue.
The error message (from the terminal) gives an segmentation fault.

How can it be that while it runs within QT, at the same time I'm getting the error using terminal?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: We would need some info here. What OS are you using and is there a window manager. Have you checked where you get the segfault (using a debugger)?

Comment: by within QT, you mean QtCreator ?

Comment: maybe the dll of Qt are not in your PATH.

Comment: maybe the working directory is different from inside the IDE and the program assumes some files present in or under the working directory

Comment: Try running `gdb myprogram` manually from the terminal, then `run` to run it, then `bt` after the segfault to get the backtrace to figure out where the crash is happening.

Comment: im using ubuntu 14.04, qt-creator 4 (QT)...thanks for the other advices...ill try it